# Is it recommend that a PHP classes variables are declared, or undeclared?

Tags: php, class, undeclared-identifier

Take the following example:

```
 class MyThing {
      public function __construct($a, $b) {
           $this->a = $a; $this->b = $b;
      }
 }
```

Do the PHP authors recommend using the above approach, or declaring `$a` and `$b` with `private $a = "default"` or `protected $b = "default"`, etc?

Comment: I can't fathom the value of not declaring them. That can only lead to confusion as you'll have no canonical place to see what variables your class has. I also can see no upside. Just don't do it (or rather, do it...the declaring, that is).

Comment: I can think of one upside to declaring them - IDE integration.

Comment: "upside" was referring to not declaring them. Obviously, there are plenty of upsides to declaring them.

Comment: As an aside, consider that in most good languages you *must* declare members before you can assign values to them. The fact that PHP even allows what you have there has always driven me up the wall.

Answer (score 3):

If you know a variable is going to exist, then yes, it is a good idea to declare it explicitly.  Sometimes you'll want to create a PHP class that will have dynamic members which go undeclared, but the vast majority of the time you will know the variables a class will use, and therefore will create more readable, maintainable code by explicitly declaring them.

I could go and find a citation of what, exactly, "the PHP authors recommend", but really the question you should be asking is "is it a good idea" - and no, it is not a good idea to intentionally leave variables undeclared.  It's sloppy, and will come back to bite you later.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better to declare them like this:

```
 class MyThing {
    private $a;
    private $b;

    public function __construct($a, $b) {
        $this->a = $a;
        $this->b = $b;
    }
}
```

Being able to add new properties to an individual object "on-the-fly" can be useful, but should only be used in situations where you can't predict what property name will be needed ahead of time. For one thing, all such properties become public properties (and it's better to keep properties private in many cases for the purposes of [encapsulation](http://www.inf.ufsc.br/poo/smalltalk/ibm/tutorial/oop.html#enca)). It also makes the code in the class much less readable if new properties are being declared all over the place.

Comment: If you're talking about using `$MyThing->{ ... }`, I would have to disagree. You can simply use a private array add new properties to an object `on the fly`. You could even use getters and setters to manage that private array. The only uses for `->{}` is really to traverse objects coming from `json_decode` or `simplexml_load_*`. You really shouldn't be using it to manage your own personal classes.

Comment: @DaveChen Sometimes I have an object whose properties I want to display in a view template and it has 90% of the properties I need but I just need to add a few more for display purposes (e.g. calculated values). While I *could* convert all such objects to `stdClass` objects or arrays and then add the new properties, it seems simpler to take advantage of the fact that PHP lets me simply add new properties to the original object. Since this is usually the last thing I do with the object before the HTTP request ends, I don't see a problem with this.

Comment: I would agree with you with regard to code *within* the class however, as in the OP's example.

Comment: I'm sorry if my earlier comment was confusing. I was pointing out that using `->{...}` is bad, because I was under the assumption that you didn't know the property name. However, if you do know the property name, and you're simply adding values on like, `$template->_dirtyX = 12`, I feel that's fine.

Comment: My statement was obviously confusing too; when I said you might not know the property name, I meant not knowing it at the time you're writing the class, not the time that you're writing the code to use it (e.g. to prepare data for a template).

Answer (score 0):

You should declare each variable (or to be crystal clear in an object, property) because otherwise an exception could be thrown if you attempt to access a property that doesn't exist because the value is yet to be set.

You can define each property as `private` to begin with if you don't know if you need the property to be protected etc.

Comment: Good point about a possible exception (technically a PHP notice) but it's a bad idea to use `var` just because you're not sure if a property should be private or protected. If you're not sure, make it private - you can always make it public later if it should really be public. Otherwise you're probably breaking encapsulation from the get-go.

Comment: P.S. I wasn't the one who downvoted but whoever did probably did so because of your recommendation to use `var`.

Comment: Fair point, answer changed.

Comment: Not the downvoter either, but [nothing will be thrown](https://eval.in/private/ce5d33ecd8e7e7), you'll get some warnings though.